# How to filter response in multi search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using python's client of elasticsearch 6.5 for multi search since I have to fetch data from multiple indexes with different queries and aggregations.

```
GET _msearch/
{
  "index": QUESTION_INDEX
}
{
  "aggs": {
    "order_info":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "order_ids",
        "size": 9999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_value": {
          "sum": "selling_price"
        }
      }
    },
    "median_price": {
      "percentiles_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "order_info>total_value",
        "percents": [50]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in my response I am getting the order_info bucket but I only need the percentile value. So is there any way to filter out this bucket from response of elasticsearch?

Edit 1: I want to reduce the response size which is coming over network call from es